# set markerColor of leaflet AwesomeMarkers to 'none / transparent'

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to use the leaflet AwesomeMarkers (https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers). However there is no possibility to not set a marker color. That means, I just want to have the icon on the map, with a transparent markerColor.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: you can use opacity also in `div` tag and prevent css apply to child tag..It will give u transparent background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fiddle that leaves out the color:

http://jsfiddle.net/VPzu4/861/

I've set the markerColor to `transparent` which results in the marker getting the class `awesome-marker-icon-transparent` and then I've defined my own style for that class which just removes the background for the icon.

Note that this will probably break something if Leaflet.awesome-markers ever decides to use the `transparent` keyword in a different way.

Update:

To get rid of the shadow you could hide the entire `leaflet-shadow-pane` by css but that would hide all the shadows.

To set the size of the marker you can try applying more css rules to `awesome-marker-icon-transparent` or you can pass in the `extraClasses` property which is used to add classes to the icon element.

There's also the possibility that one of the 160 forks in GitHub already does what you want.

Comment: any idea how to set the size of this marker except via the font? So that i could set the size for each marker individually?

Comment: You can change the size of an icon marker like so: L.icon({ iconUrl: 'images/customIcon.png', iconSize: [24,24]  }); See this page in docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon

Answer (score 2):

for `@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet` packet in Vue 3. `@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet` version is `0.10.1`.

```scss
.leaflet-div-icon {
  background: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```